# What is this Anonymous / Unknown button on google chrome browser window?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome, browser, bug

#### What is this button / part which is taking my browsing portion in google chrome?

[image: screenshot sample]

*I am so curious to know what made this to pop up on my window.*

**I can confirm that this is only on a particular chrome window. When i tried opening new window, it wasn't there**

**Even though it look like 2 buttons  ,  it's not clickable & Not able to remove it without closing the window**

*PS: I haven't closed the window yet , because this may be only time i can find this bug/something*
[image: screenshot sample]

Comment: It’s not very clear what button you’re refering to. Please include an image (not a link) in this question of just the button (or annotated to clearly show what button you mean).

Comment: @StarCat i have updated the question with image

Comment: Could be an extension. Could also be a bug of some kind. If you restart the browser does it come back?

Comment: @Pheric no it wasn't there when i restarted

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is part of an extension or plugin you are running.

To see if this is the case:

1. Go to manage extensions (see the puzzle button next to your google account button in the top right corner)
2. Switch off all extensions
3. restart chrome and see if it pops back up like you experienced before

If this solves it, you know it is one of your extensions. If so, you can check out which one by turning them on one at a time and see when it comes back. The help page of your plugin will tell you what it is for.